# My spam flag was declined so I'm posting about it here

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, spam

I consider [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30024514/607407) a fake question. Please check [what the title originally looked like](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30024514/revisions). The user makes the [same attempts to propagate that url in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024514/dynamic-values-from-database-working-fine-on-localhost-bt-not-comming-on-server#comment48169075_30025918).

I think it's not my flag but the moderator who declined it who should be marked as *not helpful*.

[image: image description]

I feel butthurt because this means I now have 6 total declined flags instead of 5.

Comment: When it's non-obvious that the content is spam, use an "other" flag (or both flags) and explain why you think it's spam.

Comment: "declined" *is* "not helpful". Sorry if the wording bothers you so much.

Comment: And your question is... ?

Comment: FYI, "butthurt" is generally considered impolite and unserious. You probably do not want to use it here (or in many other contexts, either).

Comment: @EdCottrell I know. I didn't mean the last sentence very seriously. Just wanted to point out that I am kinda proud of my flag score and I don't like it being ruined.

Comment: Refreshing that someone who is butthurt comes to meta and says so, rather than angrily demanding everything change so their fanny ache goes away.  Errbody gets butthurt, err once in awhile.  Honestly admitting your pooper pain is the first step to recovery.  Check with your doctor before proceeding. Some people report erections in excess of four hours. Seek medical attention first. I'm stuck in a pecker pill advertisement, please send help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not spam by the Stack Exchange definition.

- It's not advertising.
- It's not promoting a product, service or website.

Just because a question contains a link doesn't automatically make it spam. People think that including a link to their site which demonstrates the problem they are having is helpful, when in reality it rarely is.

However, it is a poor question that should be:

- Edited
- Downvoted
- Closed

Though the latter two can be avoided if the first action is taken.

Comment: Further thinking about it, user probably wasn't trying to advertise his site, though I will keep an eye on it.